# How to have proper urls for nested resources in tastypie

Tags: django, tastypie

I'm using the Nested Resource cookbook pattern from tastypie, which can be found [here](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/v0.9.16/cookbook.html#nested-resources), only I'm using many-to-many relationships.

Which means the prepend urls, looks something like this:

```
class ParentResource(ModelResource):
children = fields.ToManyField(ChildResource, 'children')

def prepend_urls(self):
    return [
        url(r"^(?P<resource_name>%s)/(?P<pk>\w[\w/-]*)/childrens%s$" % (self._meta.resource_name, trailing_slash()), self.wrap_view('get_children'), name="api_get_children"),
    ]

def get_children(self, request, **kwargs):
    #some way to get the filter
    child_resource = ChildResource()
    return child_resource.get_list(request, parent_id=obj.pk)
```

this works fine, except that pagination uses the child resource's url rather then the url in prepend__urls.
I.E. instead of:

```
"meta": {
    "limit": 1,
    "next": "/api/parent/1/childrens?limit=1&offset=1",
    "offset": 0,
    "previous": null,
    "total_count": 2
},
```

I get:

```
"meta": {
    "limit": 1,
    "next": "/api/parent/?limit=1&offset=1",
    "offset": 0,
    "previous": null,
    "total_count": 2
},
```

is there anyway t get the pagination urls to display properly?

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this doing  following:

1. Use a "custom_uri" argument on the get_list method of the child resource.
   To do that you have to reimplement the full method:

```python
def get_list(self, request, **kwargs):
    """
    Returns a serialized list of resources.

    Calls ``obj_get_list`` to provide the data, then handles that result
    set and serializes it.

    Should return a HttpResponse (200 OK).
    """
    # TODO: Uncached for now. Invalidation that works for everyone may be
    #       impossible.

    base_bundle = self.build_bundle(request=request)
    objects = self.obj_get_list(bundle=base_bundle, **self.remove_api_resource_names(kwargs))
    sorted_objects = self.apply_sorting(objects, options=request.GET)

    if 'custom_uri' in kwargs:
        resource_uri = kwargs['custom_uri']
    else:
        resource_uri = self.get_resource_uri()

    paginator = self._meta.paginator_class(request.GET, sorted_objects, resource_uri=resource_uri, limit=self._meta.limit, max_limit=self._meta.max_limit, collection_name=self._meta.collection_name)
    to_be_serialized = paginator.page()

    # Dehydrate the bundles in preparation for serialization.
    bundles = []

    for obj in to_be_serialized[self._meta.collection_name]:
        bundle = self.build_bundle(obj=obj, request=request)
        bundles.append(self.full_dehydrate(bundle, for_list=True))

    to_be_serialized[self._meta.collection_name] = bundles
    to_be_serialized = self.alter_list_data_to_serialize(request, to_be_serialized)
    return self.create_response(request, to_be_serialized)
```

2. Send the correct uri on the parent method:

```python
def trip_photos(self, request, **kwargs):
    try:
        bundle = self.build_bundle(data={'pk': kwargs['pk']}, request=request)
        obj = self.cached_obj_get(bundle=bundle, self.remove_api_resource_names(kwargs))
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        return HttpGone()
    except MultipleObjectsReturned:
        return HttpMultipleChoices("More than one resource is found at this URI.")

    custom_uri = self._build_reverse_url('api_get_children', kwargs=self.resource_uri_kwargs(bundle))

    child_resource = ChildResource()
    return child_resource.get_list(request, parent_id=obj.pk, custom_uri=custom_uri)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is the approximation that should be changed. Why don't you just get the children ( children goes without 's', already plural ;) ) related to a parent from the `ChildResource`?

```
http://SERVER/api/v1/child/?parent=1&limit=1&offset=1
```

No problems with pagination then.

Comment: There are several reasons why not to, first is that we want the api to be a certain way.

But also in some of the use cases we want to limit it by complex rules (such as using the request.user) or searching by more then one nested key (which would be inconvienent to write).